# Usage of the java function 'split()

Tags: java, function, split, advanced-search

I would like to split the word in java based on the delimeter'-'when it appeared last.

I am expecting the result as "sweet_memory_in" and  "everbodylife@gmail.com". Do we have any inbuilt function in java.

Complete word is sweet_memory_in_everbodylife@gmail.com

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: You can use `lastIndexOf` and make two `substring`s

Comment: That's easily done with String methods lastIndexOf() and substring()

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    String s = "sweet_memory_in_everbodylife@gmail.com";
    String s1 = s.substring(0,s.lastIndexOf("_"));
    String s2 = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("_")+1,s.length());
```

Comment: I think s2 should be String s2 = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("_")+1,s.length());

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "sweet_memory_in_everbodylife@gmail.com";
String first = s.substring(0,s.lastIndexOf("_"));
String second = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("_")+1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex may help. Other way is to get the last index of _ and use substring to split it.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code :

```
        String data = "sweet_memory_in_everbodylife@gmail.com";
    int lastIndex = data.lastIndexOf("_");

    String firstSplit = data.substring(0, lastIndex);
    String secondSplit = data.substring(lastIndex + 1, data.length());

    System.out.println(firstSplit);
    System.out.println(secondSplit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this my friend (Javascript Codes):

```
var str = 'sweet_memory_in_everbodylife@gmail.com';
var arr1 = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("_")).split("_");
var arr2 = str.split("_"+arr1[1]);
alert(arr2[0] +" --> "+arr1[1]);
```